# How to add "slope" function (excel) in R

Tags: r, excel, lm

I'm trying to move data wrangling from excel to R.
I have a dataframe (df) with 62 columns and 21 rows. Each of the rows represents a different organisation, and each of the column headings (apart from the first one which gives organisation name) are monthly dates.

The structure looks like this:

```
structure(list(OrgCode = c("RA", "RB", "RC", "RD"), Provider = c("ORGA", 
"ORGB", "ORGC", 
"ORGD"), `Jan-22` = c(0.54, 
0.78, 0.715399610136452, 0.37), `Feb-22` = c(0.14, 
0.43, 0.65, 0.87)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My excel spreadsheet uses the slope() function to take the 3 most recent dates and calculate the slope of them. I want to create a new column in my df in R which contains the slope of the 3 last columns of my df but I can't figure out how to do this.

I've seen some code suggesting taking a linear regression for each provider:

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
cf <- coef(mod)
Slope <- cf[2]
```

but I don't know how to save a model (which only uses the last three dates not all the dates available in the dataframe) in a column and then create another column which takes the date of this - seems like there should be a simple function which exists.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share some example data with structure like yours. Otherwise we are left imagining what it might look like, and are likely to imagine incorrectly. It could be as simple as running `dput(YOUR_DATA[1:4,1:4])` and pasting the output into the body of your question. That will make a code "recipe" that reproduces the first 4 rows and  4 columns of your data, formats and all.

Comment: In general, I expect this will be simpler if you reshape your data longer, so that you have a column for Org, a column for Month, and a column for Value for that Org-Month.

Answer (score 0):

A lazy approach.. `slope` function takes 3 last columns - you must make sure that's the proper one with last dates.

```r
df <- structure(
  list(
    OrgCode = c("RA", "RB", "RC", "RD"),
    Provider = c("ORGA", "ORGB", "ORGC", "ORGD"),
    `Jan-22` = c(0.54, 0.78, 0.715399610136452, 0.37),
    `Feb-22` = c(0.14, 0.43, 0.65, 0.87),
    `Mar-22` = c(0.54, 0.78, 0.715399610136452, 0.37),
    `Apr-22` = c(0.84, 1.43, 0.9, 0.07)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -4L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

slope <- function(df = "", row_number = 1L) {
  df <- df[,c((ncol(df)-2):ncol(df))]
  sl <- lm(c(df[row_number, 1][[1]], df[row_number, 2][[1]], df[row_number, 3][[1]]) ~ c(1, 2, 3)) |>
    coef() |>
    purrr::pluck(2)
  return(sl)
}

slope(df, 1)
#> [1] 0.35

slope(df, 3)
#> [1] 0.125

sla <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  sla <- slope(df, i) |>
    rbind(sla)
}
df$slope <- rev(unlist(sla))
df
#>   OrgCode Provider    Jan-22 Feb-22    Mar-22 Apr-22  slope
#> 1      RA     ORGA 0.5400000   0.14 0.5400000   0.84  0.350
#> 2      RB     ORGB 0.7800000   0.43 0.7800000   1.43  0.500
#> 3      RC     ORGC 0.7153996   0.65 0.7153996   0.90  0.125
#> 4      RD     ORGD 0.3700000   0.87 0.3700000   0.07 -0.400
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-29 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can define slope as shown below.

For example if we want to calculate the slope separately on each row for the last n=2 columns:

```
library(dplyr)

slope <- function(y, x = seq_along(y)) cov(x, y) / var(x)

n <- 2  # take slope of last n columns on each row
DF %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(slope = slope(c_across(seq(to = last_col(), length = n)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  OrgCode Provider `Jan-22` `Feb-22`   slope
  <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 RA      ORGA        0.54      0.14 -0.4   
2 RB      ORGB        0.78      0.43 -0.35  
3 RC      ORGC        0.715     0.65 -0.0654
4 RD      ORGD        0.37      0.87  0.5
```

### Note

The input DF from the question is

```
DF <- 
structure(list(OrgCode = c("RA", "RB", "RC", "RD"), Provider = c("ORGA", 
"ORGB", "ORGC", 
"ORGD"), `Jan-22` = c(0.54, 
0.78, 0.715399610136452, 0.37), `Feb-22` = c(0.14, 
0.43, 0.65, 0.87)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```