# Calculate new column giving trend/slope across other columns using data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, regression

I have a very large table in R, with numeric columns giving values across several years. It looks something like this, but with many more columns and several million rows.

```
id    year1   year2   year3   year4
ac       44      34      23      34
as       12      15      25      45
df       99      88     107     114
```

I would like to calculate a new column giving the trend over time of the numeric columns. I guess this could be the slope of a regression on the numeric columns. How could I calculate this for each row in an efficient manner? Suggestions using `data.table` would be ideal.

So far I've been able to do this by re-shaping the data to long, and performing a regression by `id`. I wondered if there was a more efficient way to do it without needing to re-shape.

Comment: There was very similar question just few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78083114/how-to-add-slope-function-excel-in-r/78083529#78083529

Comment: *"could be the slope of a regression"* really is too vague. Do you "know" what you want the new column to contain given this sample data? If you're asking for "how to code something", then you need to know what the results should be. If you're asking for "what kind of projection can I do here", then this is about statistics and would benefit from more theoretical discussions about forecasting on [stats.se]. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the linear regression manually can handle 1e7 rows and 50 columns in a few seconds:

```
library(Rfast) # for `rowmeans`
library(data.table)

# example data
set.seed(509437570)
nr <- 1e7 # number of rows
nc <- 50 # number of columns
dt <- data.table(id = 1:nr)[
  ,paste0("year", 1:nc) :=
    as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(nr*nc, 0, 5) + outer(runif(nr), 1:nc), nr, nc))
]

system.time(
  dt[
    ,c("slope", "intercept") := .(
      slope <- (((m <- as.matrix(.SD)) - (ybar <- rowmeans(m))) %*%
        (dx <- seq(-(nc - 1)/2, (nc - 1)/2)))/sum(dx^2),
      ybar - slope*(nc + 1)/2
    ), .SDcols = paste0("year", 1:nc)
  ]
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    4.56    0.96    3.66

dt[1:5, c("id", "slope", "intercept")]
#>    id     slope  intercept
#> 1:  1 0.1821816  2.6856957
#> 2:  2 0.3254113  0.1084359
#> 3:  3 0.4975937  0.4861745
#> 4:  4 0.3796465  1.0722193
#> 5:  5 0.6800638 -0.3818551
```

Plot the first row with its fit:

```
plot(1:nc, unlist(dt[1, 2:(nc + 1)]))
abline(dt$intercept[1], dt$slope[1])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm never seen the `Rfast` or `collapse` packages before, so not entirely sure how it's working, but it seems to work well. I'll have to read about those packages

Comment: I forgot to note why I was pulling in those packages. I'm using `Rfast` for the `rowmeans` function, which is faster than `rowMeans` (especially on large matrices). It turns out `setop` from `collapse` wasn't needed (see the update).

Comment: Oops. I think I accidentally deleted the example data in the last update. It's back.